# GitLab CE 9: how to upgrade to new user interface

Tags: gitlab

I'm using the docker image at https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/.
To be specific, I'm using the image gitlab/gitlab-ce:9.3.2-ce.0.
Still getting the old UI. Was the new UI a feature of gitlab.com, not gitlab CE?

This is a example of what the UI should look like as in the GitLab landing page screenshots:

[image]

... versus what I am getting:

[image]

The official screenshots show a sticky vertical navbar for project level links, while I have a horizontal one.

Running the docker image mentioned should be enough to reproduce the issue.

```
sudo docker run --detach \
    --hostname gitlab.example.com \
    --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
    --name gitlab \
    --restart always \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
    gitlab/gitlab-ce:9.3.2-ce.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new UI was [introduced](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/07/22/gitlab-9-4-released/#new-navigation) in Gitlab CE 9.4. Once you have upgraded to 9.4.0 or above, you need to go into your profile preferences and activate the new layout.